# Grouping the data and showing 1 row per group in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables which look like this :-

Component Table

[image]

Revision Table

[image]

I want to get the name,model_id,rev_id from this table such that the result set has the data like shown below :-

```
name    model_id    rev_id  created_at
ABC     1234        2       23456
ABC     5678        2       10001
XYZ     4567
```

Here the data is grouped by name,model_id and only 1 data for each group is shown which has the highest value of created_at.

I am using the below query but it is giving me incorrect result.

```
SELECT cm.name,cm.model_id,r.created_at from dummy.component cm 
left join dummy.revision r on cm.model_id=r.model_id 
group by cm.name,cm.model_id,r.created_at
ORDER BY cm.name asc,
r.created_at DESC;
```

Result :-

[image]

Anyone's help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use `max and sub-query`

```
select T1.name,T1.model_id,r.rev_id,T1.created_at  from      

(
select cm.name,
    cm.model_id,    
    MAX(r.created_at) As created_at from dummy.component cm 
    left join dummy.revision r on cm.model_id=r.model_id 
    group by cm.name,cm.model_id

) T1
left join revision r
  on T1.created_at =r.created_at
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/68cb5/4

```
name    model_id    rev_id  created_at
ABC       1234       2           23456
ABC       5678       2           10001
xyz       4567
```

Comment: @Sunny please check now

Comment: Syntax issue with ur sql -- ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"
LINE 20:   on T1.name=T.name  and T1.model_id=T.model_id

Comment: @Sunny that on clause little bit mistake eidited check plz now

Comment: Ur query does not return the rev_id .. If i do T1.rev_id it returns me the incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

In your SELECT you're missing rev_id

Try this:

```
SELECT 
cm.name,
cm.model_id,
MAX(r.rev_id) AS rev_id,
MAX(r.created_at) As created_at
from dummy.component cm 
left join dummy.revision r on cm.model_id=r.model_id 
group by 1,2
ORDER BY cm.name asc,
r.created_at DESC;
```

What you were missing is the statement to say you only want the max record from the join table. So you need to join records, but the join will bring in all records from table r. If you group by the 2 columns in component, then select the max from r, on the id and created date, it'll only pick the top out the available to join

Comment: No Luck getting the same result as i was getting earlier.

Comment: I missed your line about only wanting the max created_at

Comment: See the new query

Comment: Getting this exception ERROR: column "r.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

I would use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (m.id) m.id, m.name, r.rev_id, r.created_at
from model m left join
     revision r
     on m.model_id = r.model_id
order by m.id, r.rev_id;
```